# Disable Excel link cell follow click

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink, links, cells

This is probably the worst design choice I've seen in my life, and it drives me mad.

I need to edit some excel spreadsheets which contain links and move some cells around, and each time I click on a cell with a link it opens the link in the browser.

It makes the work a hell so much that I chose to upload them to google, edit them there and then downloading them.

It has to be a way out of this madness

How can I activate some kind of feature like Ctrl+Click or Double Click on links to follow them, and disable the autofollow link?

I've searched high and low and can't find to option.

Comment: Click and Hold for about 1 second.

Comment: right click then left click